# Expression of non-boolean type specified

Tags: t-sql, boolean, syntax-error

Can't figure out why this query won't run, because its saying I don't have a Boolean statement where one should be.

The error I'm getting says:

> An error occurred while executing the query.
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'. (Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder)
>
> Server Name: xxxxxxxxxx
>   Error Number: 4145
>   Severity: 15
>   State: 1
>   Line Number: 9

```
SELECT 
REF_TPI_NPI_PHYS.MNE,
REF_TPI_NPI_PHYS.REFERRING,
RPT_MK_PRACT_PHYS_PT_CNT.COUNT_PTS AS TOTAL_PTS,
Sum(IIf(HBA1C_DATE IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS COUNT_HBA1C,

Format((Sum(IIf(HBA1C_DATE IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) / ([RPT_MK_PRACT_PHYS_PT_CNT].COUNT_PTS)), 'Percent') AS PANELED_HBA1C,

Format(Sum(IIf(HBA1C_VALUE IS NOT NULL AND IsNumeric(CAST(HBA1C_VALUE AS FLOAT)) AND CAST(HBA1C_VALUE AS FLOAT) <= 100, 1, 0))) / Sum(IIf(HBA1C_DATE IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)), 'Percent') AS HBA1C_COMP

Sum(IIf(LDL_DATE IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS COUNT_LDL,

Format((Sum(IIf(LDL_DATE IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) / ([RPT_MK_PRACT_PHYS_PT_CNT].COUNT_PTS)), 'Percent') AS PANELED_LDL,

Format(Sum(IIf(LDL_VALUE IS NOT NULL AND IsNumeric(CAST(LDL_VALUE AS FLOAT)) AND CAST(LDL_VALUE AS FLOAT) <= 100, 1, 0))) / Sum(IIf(LDL_DATE IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)), 'Percent') AS LDL_COMP

FROM 
(
  (
    TBL_HBA1C_LDL LEFT JOIN TBL_REGISTRATION
    ON CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(TBL_HBA1C_LDL.PAT_MRN)) AS INTEGER) = TBL_REGISTRATION.MRN
  ) 

  LEFT JOIN 
  REF_TPI_NPI_PHYS
  ON TBL_REGISTRATION.PCP = REF_TPI_NPI_PHYS.REFERRING
)

LEFT JOIN 
RPT_MK_PRACT_PHYS_PT_CNT
ON TBL_REGISTRATION.PCP = RPT_MK_PRACT_PHYS_PT_CNT.PCP 

GROUP BY 
REF_TPI_NPI_PHYS.MNE,
REF_TPI_NPI_PHYS.REFERRING,
RPT_MK_PRACT_PHYS_PT_CNT.COUNT_PTS

ORDER BY 
REF_TPI_NPI_PHYS.MNE,
REF_TPI_NPI_PHYS.REFERRING
```

Comment: "IIf", "IsNumeric" and "Format" are not T-SQL functions.

Comment: @RazvanSocol yes they are. Is numeric is ancient and the other two since 2012.

Comment: You are using `IsNumeric` as though it is a Boolean predicate such as `EXISTS`.

In fact it returns a bit value of `0` or `1` so you need to test the value with `=1`

I.e.

    `AND IsNumeric(CAST(LDL_VALUE AS FLOAT)) AND`

Needs to be


    `AND IsNumeric(CAST(LDL_VALUE AS FLOAT)) = 1 AND`

But this is utterly pointless anyway as if the value is not numeric the cast will have already thrown an error.